# Docker MySQL 8 how to set --secure-file-priv

Tags: mysql, docker, parameter-passing, config

I would like to solve this problem:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

with the [official MySQL 8](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/a7a737f1eb44db467c85c8229df9d886dd63460e/8.0/Dockerfile) image on docker.

the command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

gives:

```
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv | NULL  |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Is it possible to overwrite the default value NULL for the --secure-file-priv by using the official MySQL 8 Docker image?

the default value in this image is set to NULL
[config/my.cnf](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/config/my.cnf#L26)

Perfectly I would like to set just an environmental variable or parameter when using docker run or create instead of bringing my own config file.

but if this is not possible then how to use custom config file?
is it possible that custom file just overwrites this one parameter and leaves others as they are in the official image config?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-file-priv), you can configure `secure-file-priv` through command-line by passing `--secure-file-priv=dir_name`

secure-file-priv possible values are: empty string, dirname or NULL as explained in the privous url.

From [mysql-docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql):

> **Configuration without a cnf file**: Many configuration options can be passed as flags to mysqld. This will give you the flexibility to customize the container without needing a cnf file. For example, if you want to change the default encoding and collation for all tables to use UTF-8 (utf8mb4) just run the following:

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

So in our case would be like this:

> **dir_name** should be a directory inside your container otherwise you will get the following error: `mysqld: Error on realpath() on 'dir_name' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)`

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag --secure-file-priv=dir_name
```

And now our change is committed in MySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+----------+
| Variable_name    | Value    |
+------------------+----------+
| secure_file_priv | dir_name |
+------------------+----------+
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom configuration file as explained in here:

> **Using a custom MySQL configuration file**: The default configuration for MySQL can be found in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which may !includedir additional directories such as /etc/mysql/conf.d or /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d. Please inspect the relevant files and directories within the mysql image itself for more details.
>
> If /my/custom/config-file.cnf is the path and name of your custom configuration file, you can start your mysql container like this (note that only the directory path of the custom config file is used in this command):

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

This will start a new container `some-mysql` where the MySQL instance uses the combined startup settings from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf`, with settings from the latter taking precedence.

Comment: is there any way to make `dir` passed by `--secure-file-priv` as the working dir for MySQL commands like `LOAD DATA INFILE '<path-to-file>' ...` so one can perform this way `LOAD DATA INFILE './file.csv' ...` instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE 'secure-file-priv-dir/file.csv' ...` ? I tried to pass that dir as option `-w "secure-file-priv-dir"` for docker run but that did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Well, I am not sure but after testing the `load data`, i found that it works through `/var/lib/mysql` so in you do `LOAD DATA INFILE './file.csv'` it actually means `/var/lib/mysql/file.csv` accroding to what i have tested

Comment: So theoretically you can make the `secure-file-priv-dir` value to be `/var/lib/mysql` but in general i am not sure if this will be normal to use or not

Comment: good to know, I thought initially to put files into `/var/lib/mysql` but I decided it would be better to have a separate dir that you work on and put csv files/delete them due to the fact that a user who wants to `LOAD DATA INFILE` does not require access right to the dir where mysql stores database data. (`/var/lib/mysql`).